# What is the '@' sign used for in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

This is a generic question and one that may have even been asked on other forums, such as the Ember forums. But I wanted to add this into StackOverflow.

But my question is why does Ember so often use an `@` in front of it's libraries. A quick example, using an Ember component in Ember 3.4:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
```

While at the same time, I had an old project from the 2.0 days that was structured like the following:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
```

Why does Ember now include an @ sign?

Comment: It's an NPM organization :D

Comment: Oh! Haha, I guess the answer's a lot simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is an [NPM scoped package](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes). As the registry has grown naming collisions are increasingly common so scoping packages helps to both keep an organizations brands together and also avoid weirdly named packages when all the good names are already taken.